# remove spaces between specific characters, with adjacent occurrences

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, replace

I'm trying to remove spaces when they occur between two exclamation marks "!".

For instance, I tried:

`echo 'this is ! a repeated ! ! ! ! character ! ! ! here ! !' | sed 's/! !/!!/g'`

The desired output would be:

`this is ! a repeated !!!! character !!! here !!`

But I get this instead:

`this is ! a repeated !! !! character !! ! here !!`

One way would be to repeat the `sed` command, but in practice I can have an arbitrary number of '!' in my input, and I can't figure out a clean way to do this.

Comment: Use a conditional jump until no more substitution takes place. Take a look at sed's `t` and `:` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Perl's look-around assertions:

```
 perl -pe 's/!\s+(?=!)/!/g'
```

The `(?=!)` means "is followed by an exclamation mark, but don't include the exclamation mark to the matched string, and start next matching *before* it".

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` you may do a looping:

```
echo 'this is ! a repeated ! ! ! ! character ! ! ! here ! !' |
sed -e :a -e 's/! !/!!/g;ta'
```

```
this is ! a repeated !!!! character !!! here !!
```